# How to display <IPython.core.display.HTML object> in R markdown (reticulate), result from displacy.render

Tags: python, r, spacy, reticulate

I use R markdown to write a PFD document with an exploratory analysis about named entity recognition with Spacy. The follow code results in

```
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
```

when rendering the pdf:

```
library(reticulate)
use_condaenv(condaenv = "r", conda = 
"C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Scripts\\conda.exe", required = T)
```

The code with ***displacy.render*** (spaCy):

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
html = displacy.render(doc, style="ent", options=options, page=True)
display(HTML(html))
```

Any ideas how to show the IPython.core.display.HTML with R markdown?